# Waiting for a result mapped future

Tags: rust, future

I'm using the [future](https://github.com/alexcrichton/futures-rs) library and I have a future which implements `Future<T, E>`. I'd like to map this future with a function `FnOnce(T) -> D` where `D: From<E>`. Now when I want to `wait()` for this future to finsih, I'll get a `Result<Result<T, E>, D>`, however I'd like a `Result<T, D>`.

Here's some example code for better understanding:

```
struct ReadError;

enum DownloadError {
    Read(ReadError),
    Parse(ParseError),
}

impl From<ReadError> for DownloadError { ... }

fn parse(bytes: [u8; 4]) -> Result<i32, DownloadError> { ... }

fn map_and_wait<F: Future<Item = [u8; 4]; Error = ReadError>>(f: F) -> Result<i32, DownloadError> {
    match f.map(|x| parse(x)).wait() {
        Ok(Ok(x)) => Ok(x),
        Ok(Err(x)) => Err(x.into()),
        Err(x) => Err(x),
    }
}
```

What's the easiest and most understandable way of doing this (without `match`ing)?

Comment: It might be easier to answer if you provide a full code example, with the `match`ing that you want to avoid.

Comment: @PeterHall OK, I've edited my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This is for futures v0.1 (old, experimental)

I found an answer to the question:

You can just first `wait` on the future to finish, use `?` to return a potential error and then apply `parse` on it:

```
parse(f.wait()?)
```

This should have equal semantics, because, when polled, the `Future` returned by `map` executes its closure. Another solution was to map a possible error and to use `and_then`:

```
f.map_error(|x| x.into()).and_then(|x| parse(x)).wait()
```

Comment: Glad you figured it out. `?` really tidies things up!

Comment: Note that, for the very purpose of  `futures`, composition should be usually preferred over an explicit call to wait, sice it's extensible and preserve asynchronicity.
Anyway the latter line of code can be written more concisely as `f.from_err().and_then(parse).wait()`.